# Permissions for running an app in Docker container

Tags: linux, security, docker

I'm building a Docker image that runs a Ruby app, which basically is a web server that runs with [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma), and make use of several binaries, python code and other things that are present in the image.

The thing is that the binaries come from the **base** image (it's a multistage build but separated, if that makes sense), and that image was built without specifying any user (i.e. `root` user was used).

The image will be running in a [Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io/)  cluster (similar to k8s). So the questions here are:

1. Is it really risky to have only the `root` user in this image running with the `root` user? Can someone point out security concerns apart from the obvious?
2. In case it is very risky to do this, which would be the best solution here? I thought about copying everything I need from `/root/` to `/home/unprivileged_user` but there are some things that I'm not sure if would work when copied e.g. `/root/.pyenv`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the base image does not suit your needs, why not roll your own?

Comment: @DanielB yep, that's one of the other options left. I thought maybe there was a different way to do it.